# reference a subclass instance variable

Tags: inheritance

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

       public void drive(){
          spinTheWheels(subclass.getNumWheels());
       }

       public void spinTheWheels(int wheelsTotal){
          ....
       }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
     private final int numWheels = 4;

    ...
}
```

In the example above, I want to reference numWheels from Car within vehicle. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A base class never knows what is inside the subclasses, mainly because it does not know where it has been inherited. 
This is because of the way inheritance is supposed to work as well. THe sub class is supposed to add to or modify the behavior of the base class and the base class should contain the basic behavior and properties needed.

EDIT: Content added to clarify OP's comment.

If you want the base class to have a method for number of wheels, in all probability this will need to know the existence of the member property or vairable called NumberOfWheels. In this case you would need to declare this within the base Vehicle class. You will not be able to declare this variable in the derived class and use it within the base class.

I can see that you have two options here,

1. In the base class, make your GetNumberOfWheels method abstract or virtual and force the derived class to use it. In this case your dervied classess may or may not have the variables but will be forced to implement this method. For example, one of your derived class could be HoverCraft, which does not have a number of wheels variable. The GetNumberOfWheels method could return a 0 or throw an exception based on what your implementation needs to be.
2. I prefer this because this is a cleaner way of doing it. You can have an interface which has number of wheels property and a GetNumberOfWheels method. Force your child classes to implment this. Each derived class can then provide its own implementation of the property and method and you will be able to use it as you need.

Comment: Okay thanks -- Fair enough. But let's say I want to force numWheels to be declared in the Car subclass.

I can use: abstract int getNumWheels(); in the Vehicle class, for example, to force implementation of a getNumWheels() method in Car.

Is there an equivilent for forcing declaration of variables?

Comment: I do not know what other requirements you have in your base class that need to be inherited, but there does seem to be little inconsistency here. I will edit my answer above to give more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Thats not possible, you can reference only super class's variables from a subclass using "super" keyword but not vice-versa. The super class never knows anything about its sub-class.